# Deep Zoom Aspect Ratio Returning Wrong Value

Tags: silverlight, zooming

My MultiScaleImage is returning an aspect ratio of 1, when the image is a 2000x1500 png.  What's even more odd, is that the xml metadata shows 1.33 in the aspect ratio tag, but then has a height and width of 1.

What the heck am I missing here?

Thanks for any help!

**MetaData:**

```
<Metadata version="1">
  <AspectRatio>1.33333333333333</AspectRatio>
  <Image>
    <FileName>C:\Documents and Settings\asmith\Desktop\Temp\DZComposer\Testing1\Source Images\2000x1500 sample image.png</FileName>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <Width>1</Width>
    <Height>1</Height>
    <ZOrder>1</ZOrder>
    <Tag />
  </Image>
</Metadata>
```

**The dzc_output.xml agrees with this also:**

```
<Collection MaxLevel="8" TileSize="256" Format="jpg" NextItemId="1" ServerFormat="Default" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/deepzoom/2009">
  <Items>
    <I Id="0" N="0" Source="dzc_output_images/2000x1500%20sample%20image.xml">
      <Size Width="2000" Height="1500" />
      <Viewport Width="1" X="-0" Y="-0" />
    </I>
  </Items>
</Collection>
```

**MSI Declaration:**

```
<MultiScaleImage 
  x:Name="msi" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Width="720" Height="540"
  MouseMove="msi_MouseMove"
  MouseLeftButtonUp="msi_MouseLeftButtonUp">
</MultiScaleImage>
```

**Property outputs:**
*(based on the msi's mousemove)*

Width: 720

Height: 540

AspectRatio: **1**

Width / Aspect Ratio: 720

Logical X: 0.55555555556

Logical Y: 0.37361111111

Logical X * Width: 400

Logical Y * Width: 269

Raw X: 400

Raw Y: 269

Viewport Origin: 0,0

Viewport Width: 1

**Codebehind that populates property outputs:**

```
private void msi_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  txtWidth.Text = msi.Width.ToString();
  txtHeight.Text = msi.Height.ToString();
  txtAspectRatio.Text = msi.AspectRatio.ToString();
  txtWidthDivAR.Text = (msi.Width / msi.AspectRatio).ToString();

  Point pLogical = msi.ElementToLogicalPoint(e.GetPosition(msi));
  txtMsiX.Text = pLogical.X.ToString();
  txtMsiY.Text = pLogical.Y.ToString();
  txtLogicYxW.Text = (pLogical.Y * msi.Width).ToString();
  txtLogicXxW.Text = (pLogical.X * msi.Width).ToString();

  Point pRaw = e.GetPosition(msi);
  txtRawX.Text = pRaw.X.ToString();
  txtRawY.Text = pRaw.Y.ToString();

  txtVPO.Text = msi.ViewportOrigin.ToString();
  txtVPW.Text = msi.ViewportWidth.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dzc_output.xml's width and height are original image size in pixels, while aspect ratio in metadata is width and height of MultiScaleImage as a whole. Width and height of image in metadata are logical to multiscaleimage's size.